# Does a non-convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (viewed as a manifold) have positive Ricci curvature?

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

My question is somewhat related to [Existence of a Riemannian metric inducing a given distance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106508/existence-of-a-riemannian-metric-inducing-a-given-distance), but in a much simpler setting (as I am just starting to learn about Riemannian geometry). I hope it makes sense!

Let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact, connected, *non-convex* subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (say with smooth boundary). Assume $S$ is also of dimension $n$. (In particular, I have in mind a non-convex two-dimensional subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.)

Equip $S$ with the distance $d$ defined (in words) by 
\begin{align}
\text{For } x,y \in S, \quad d(x,y) &= \text{infimum (over all paths) of the Euclidean length of a path from $x$ to $y$}\\
&\quad \text{ which stays entirely within $S$}
\end{align}

Assuming there is a Riemannian metric $g(\cdot,\cdot)$ which is induced from this distance ($g$ will not be the Euclidean inner-product?...), can we say say anything about the Ricci curvature of the Riemannian manifold $(S,g)$ (non-negative...) ?

Obviously when $S$ is convex then $d$ is the regular Euclidean distance and $g$ is just the inner-product inherited from $\mathbb{R}^n$. If we lose convexity, it seems the curvature is no longer zero, but I don't really have a good sense for what happens.

Comment: What is the dimension of manifold $S$?  Have you tried looking at 1-dimensional manifolds in $n=2$?

Comment: Apologies, I meant to add the $S$ is also of dimension $n$ (will edit).

Comment: Have you tried looking at a non-convex 2-dimensional $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$?:)

Comment: A compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$ of topological dimension $n$ is **not** a manifold.  It might be a manifold with boundary.

Answer (score 1):

The interior of $S$ is open, hence locally convex. In an arbitrary Euclidean ball $B$ contained in $S$, the inf-of-path-lengths metric $d$ restricts to the Euclidean metric on $B$. Now, a Riemannian metric $g$ is "determined locally" by its inf-of-path-lengths metric. Since $(B, d)$ is Euclidean for every ball $B \subset S$, it follows that if a Riemannian metric $g$ on $S$ induces $d$, then $(S, g)$ is locally Euclidean, hence flat.