# Harmonic functions and coordinate transfomation

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, coordinate-systems

Related to a question about coordinates, I've been given [the following comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106508/existence-of-a-riemannian-metric-inducing-a-given-distance/673742#comment9105292_673742) to consider:

> *"Local coordinate functions are given by suitable harmonic functions on subsets of the metric space, where "harmonic" is defined in metric terms."*

Trying to comprehend and to confirm this statement leads me to the following:

Let function $h : \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a [harmonic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function) in terms of arguments $(x, y)$; i.e. $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x}\left[ h \right]+ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y}\left[ h \right] = 0.$

Now define another function, $f : \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ through

$$
\begin{align*}
f\huge[ & \, x - \text{Sgn}[ \, y \, ] \, \sqrt{ \, \text{Abs}[ \, y \, ] \, }, & ~ \\ ~ & \text{Sgn}[ \, y \, ] \, \left( \sqrt{ \text{Abs}[ \, y \, ] \, \left(\text{Abs}[ \, y \, ] + \frac{1}{4}\right)} + \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \, \text{Ln} \! \left[ \sqrt{4 \, \text{Abs}[ \, y \, ] + 1} + \sqrt{4 \, \text{Abs}[ \, y \, ]} \, \right] \right) \, {\huge]} := h[ \, x, y \, ].
\end{align*}
$$

Also, introduce new variables:

$$ p := x - \text{Sgn}[ \, y \, ] \, \sqrt{ \, \text{Abs}[ \, y \, ] \, } $$

and
$$ q := \text{Sgn}[ \, y \, ] \, \left( \sqrt{ \text{Abs}[ \, y \, ] \, \left(\text{Abs}[ \, y \, ] + \frac{1}{4}\right)} + \left( \frac{1}{4} \right) \, \text{Ln} \left[ \sqrt{4 \, \text{Abs}[ \, y \, ] + 1} + \sqrt{4 \, \text{Abs}[ \, y \, ]} \right] \right). $$

(As a motivation for these particular choices note that
$$\int_0^k \! \! \! \sqrt{1 + (2 \, x)^2} \, {\rm d}x \, = \, k \, \sqrt{k^2 + \frac{1}{4}} + \left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \, \text{Ln} \left[ \sqrt{4 \, k^2 + 1 } + 2 \, k \right],$$

where $\frac{d}{dx} \left[ x^2 \right]  = 2 \, x$, of course.
See also this "[visual suggestion](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7B2%2C+1%2C+0%2C+-1%2C+%28x+%2B+3%29+abs%28x+%2B+3%29%2C+%28x+%2B+2%29+abs%28x+%2B+2%29%2C+%28x+%2B+1%29+abs%28x+%2B+1%29%2C+x+abs%28x%29%2C+%28x+-+1%29+abs%28x+-+1%29%2C+%28x+-+2%29+abs%28x+-+2%29%2C+%28x+-+3%29+abs%28x+-+3%29%7D+x%3D-2.3..3.3+y%3D-1.8..2.8) of the appearance of $(p, q)$-coordinate lines relative to $(x, y)$-coordinate lines".)

Consequently, $f[ \, p, \, q \, ] := h[ \, x, \, y \, ],$
and there is a one-to-one correspondence (map) $\psi : \{(x, y)\} \leftrightarrow \{(p, q)\}$ as described above.

**My question:**

Is function $f$, as function $f[ \, p, \, q \, ]$, a harmonic function in terms of arguments $(p, q)$, too ? --
especially considering the particular choice of map $\psi$ between arguments $(p, q)$ of function $f$, and $(x, y)$ of function $h$.