# The connection between a Metric Tensor and a Metric in Topology

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, tensors

Does the Metric tensor define a metric on the topology of the manifold/space it's on, and/or does the metric on the topology of the space define a metric tensor, if you go through all the trouble of defining a vector space/tangent space for it to exist on?

Comment: in complete Riemannian  manifolds, yes, a metric tensor induces a distance in the manifold through minimum length of paths betwwen two points. But not in general.

Comment: As written, your question is unclear. It appears as something created by google translate or a similar program. I am voting to close due to lack of clarity.

Comment: Okay but does a metric in the topological sense define a metric tensor.

Comment: What is "a metric in the topological sense"? Do you mean: If $g$ is a Riemannian metric and $d_g$ the corresponding distance function on the manifold, does $d_g$ determine $g$?

Comment: All the topology books I’ve read started the first chapter discussing “Metric spaces” which are sets with a distance function. So by “a metric in a topological sense” I do mean a set or manifold with a distance function. I asked the question because some distance functions don’t seem like they would correspond to tensors, like the “taxi cab metric.”

Comment: Your question is very unclear, I truly do not understand what are you asking about. Edit it to explain what do you really mean. In particular, do not try to fit a question in a single sentence. Also, check if answers to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106508/existence-of-a-riemannian-metric-inducing-a-given-distance) question address the issue you are interested in.

Comment: Yeah that’s it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Note that it doesn’t even make sense to talk about a metric tensor unless you’re on a differentiable (at least $C^1$) manifold.